# Rebuild ListView after operation on List Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to refresh the list of recipes after i delete one item and i have tried using `SetState` but I've got no result. I think the issue is that i get to this screen after making a `GET call` and that call is not executed again after deleting the item. What can I do?

```
void _pushRecipesByTypeScreen(String type) async {
    var recipes = await entityApi.getRecipesByType(type);

    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(type)),
          body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: recipes.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = recipes[index];
                return _buildEntityItem2(item);
              })
      );
    }));
  }

Widget _buildEntityItem2(Entity entity) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(entity.name),
      onTap: () => _pushDeleteScreen(entity),
    );
  }  


 void _pushDeleteScreen(Entity entity) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new AlertDialog(
              title: new Text('Delete "${entity.name}"?'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('CANCEL'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('CONFIRM'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _removeEntityItem(entity);
                      setState(() {});
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    })
              ]);
        });
  }

  void _removeEntityItem(Entity entity) async {
    if (await connectivity.checkConnectivity() != ConnectivityResult.none) {
      bool success = await entityApi.deleteEntity(entity);
      if (success) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The setstate should be used outside of dialog for it to reload your listview

```
    void _pushRecipesByTypeScreen(String type) async {
    var recipes = await entityApi.getRecipesByType(type);

    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(type)),
          body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: recipes.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = recipes[index];
                return _buildEntityItem2(item);
              })
      );
    }));
  }

Widget _buildEntityItem2(Entity entity) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(entity.name),
      onTap: () async {
       if(await _pushDeleteScreen(entity)) {
            await _removeEntityItem(entity); //await until this completes
            setState(() {});
       }
    }
    );
  }  


 Future<bool> _pushDeleteScreen(Entity entity) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new AlertDialog(
              title: new Text('Delete "${entity.name}"?'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('CANCEL'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false)),
                new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('CONFIRM'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                    })
              ]);
        });
  }

  // make this return future
  Future<void> _removeEntityItem(Entity entity) async {
    if (await connectivity.checkConnectivity() != ConnectivityResult.none) {
      bool success = await entityApi.deleteEntity(entity);
      if (success) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: but `_pushDeleteScreen(entity)` is of type void I cannot use it in the if

Comment: it's still the same.. is there any way i could retrigger the `var recipes = await entityApi.getRecipesByType(type);` after the successful deletion?

Comment: check the latest edit, also if you save recipies as property of stateful widget, then you can retrigger same way you trigger any other variables..using setState,